# PowerShell Script special variable "$?" returning different values for Tableau tabadmin command

Tags: powershell, backup, tableau-api

I'm having some trouble with the power-shell special variable "`$?` " when executed for tableau server `tabadmin` command .

Short example :

If I run the following :

```
tabadmin backup 
Write-Output $?
```

it will return the correct value both from the PowerShell ISE and from the command line tool/task scheduler which would be `True`  , but if I run the follwing:

```
tabadmin asldkfnaslkd 
Write-Output $?
```

I would expect it to exit with an error and "$?" to be False , It does this from the PowerShell ISE **but not from the command line tool/ task scheduler** . In the command line tool and task scheduler I get  `$?` as `True` ,which is very weird .

Did anyone had this issue already , some hints would be greatly appreciated .

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$?` is an [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx):

> `$?` contains the execution status of the last operation. It contains TRUE
>   if the last operation succeeded and FALSE if it failed.

It's `True` in both cases, because PowerShell is able to execute your command successfully: executable is found and launched.

What you really want to know is exit code, and to get it you should use `$LastExitCode`. It contains the exit code of the last Windows-based program that was run.

Check if this exit code is the same in PS ISE/PS console, this may shed some light on their behaviour.

Comment: It returns 0 in both cases , i think there is an issue with the tabadmin command , which does not return the correct exit code .

Comment: I can't say right now without my work computer, but I suspect that "tabadmin blah" will result in the help information being provided (since "blah" isn't a recognised tabadmin command) and that will return TRUE because the operation technically succeeded. Try and see?

Comment: I've had a case with tableau  , and seems they solved this in a newer version